# Jquery easy ui datagrid

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using jquery easy ui datagrid. Have a requirement of caching the each datagrid page data, but not able to find the soluton.

While moving from one page to another page, datagrid is sending requiest to app server and refreshing the existing data.I need to stop database hit to refrain the datagrid from overriding the edited data.how can we achieve this?

Comment: the title should say more.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you **maybe** implement yourself but it is very complected.
in general you'll have to be registered to events of the datagrid.

`onLoadSuccess` - you just take the state of the grid with the data param and save it in js global array.

each time you hit `onBeforeLoad` you take the grid state and check with the array from above if it has the data in, and change the grid remotly. if the data really found in onBeforeLoad  you need to return false, so it wont go to the server.

**Again**, there is no built in functionality and I **doubt** if it achievable with out adding more events to the lib source code.